# Jquery-No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: jquery, json

I have request json data from other website, but it meets the problem of access control allow origin in header, I have no idea how to set the access control allow origin in header, I'm put my source code in the iis8 to access the json data from another iis8 api source.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url:rootURL,
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: false
    },

    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: ": "GET",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: ": "Authorization",
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {   
    },
    error: function() {
        alert("An error occurred while processing JSON file.");
    }
});
```

Comment: It's the server that should send those headers, not the client.

Comment: server has to set those headers, not the request and you can't tell it to. If it's not enabled on server you need to go alternate ways to get data. This is very easy to research

Comment: I have add them in the web.config file in server and solve it already! Tq so much!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These should be in the server, not the client:

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ": "*",
```

To implement that in server, for PHP:

```
<?php
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
```

For ASP.NET:

```
Response.AppendHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

For others, check [I want to add CORS support to my server](http://enable-cors.org/server.html) for more information.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!
I have solve it with it~
But now for the other method like put, delete, update, it occurs 
Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404 error
May I know how to solve it in proper, tq so much